# Gerar PDF com imagens Ionic

Tags: ionic, apache-cordova, pdf

Preciso gerar um PDF dentro de um APP híbrido desenvolvido com Ionic.

Tentei utilizar os principais plugins, tais como [pdf-generator](https://github.com/cesarvr/pdf-generator) porém acabo sempre esbarrando no mesmo problema, que são as imagens que não aparecem.

As imagens do app, são armazenadas no store, pois o mesmo trabalha offline. O pdf gera todo certo, mas as imagens não, já conferi path e tentei diversas abordagens.

Comment: Como as imagens estão armazenadas no store, elas estão em base64, correto? Vc está colocando corretamente a tag img para base64 no HTML de origem do pdf?  Tipo isso aqui:  <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />

Comment: Sim elas estão carregadas no store, eu recebo elas via requisição e faço upload para dentro do store, porem carrego elas via path 
ex: "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/nome-imagem"

O meu problema parece ser que por se path, dentro do plugin que gera o pdf ele não reconhece o mesmo, ou não tem acesso.

Comment: Com path não rola, tentou o exemplo q passei no comentário?

Comment: sim tentei, e tambem não funcionou.

O problema deve ser pelo path então.